# Compare two pictures with each other with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, image-recognition

Is it possible to compare two images with Ionic?

The scenario would be this: I have a database with 50 different images of different flowers and corresponding metadata like title and description. If I now take a picture of a flower with my smartphone, can I assign this picture to another one to find the most suitable result?

Do I need services like the Google Cloud Vision API to do this? Or can I do it internally because I already have the database?

PS: If a server is required, Cloud Functions would be a possibility. For example, programming in Python would be possible there.

Answer (score 0):

**No Ionic cannot do this.**

Ionic is just a UI framework that allows you to build cross-platform apps and specifically mobile apps (iOS, Android, [formerly] WindowsMobile).

What you're trying to do is something that another system could do. Check out [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/about/),
which would be more suitable for your purposes, and then you can use Ionic to build a nice interface around it.